# Join multiple tables on known ID

Tags: mysql, join

I have multiple (13 in numbers) tables that have one thing in common: Their ID.

Point is that I need to query the results (can differ from none to multiple per table) for a single ID and return all results that have that ID - it's no UID.

I have one table that should/could be the "starting" point from where the other tables get connected and where the questioned ID is present in every case.

Don't want to post what I've tried so far - I want to avoid the laughes. Reading what I write in Mysql is close to see a child walking it's first steps. Cute and ... funny.

Thanks for any hint, suggestion and nice comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand you have one parent table with ID values and many similar child tables that should be connected to parent table. Check this query. Is it what you want?

```
SELECT * FROM parent_table t
LEFT JOIN child_table1 t1
  ON t.id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN child_table2 t2
  ON t.id = t2.id
...
LEFT JOIN child_table<n> t<n>
  ON t.id = t<n>.id
```

Or this variant; in this case all child tables will be returned in rows -

```
SELECT * FROM parent_table t
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM child_table1
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT * FROM child_table2
  UNION ALL 
  ...
  SELECT * FROM child_table<n>
  UNION ALL
) t1
ON t.id = t1.id
```

Comment: It's close to that (I guess). The thing I need is all entries over all tables that share (for example) the ID of "6" with the parent table. Btw: Sure that the `ON t.id = t1.id` is correct in the second example? :)

Comment: @Kaiser: Yes, it is correct. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html and for further reading see: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: @nikc Already knew the coddinghorror link - nice explanation. The 1st example kind of works. Strange as it is: At a "higher" number of tables involved it starts repeating results (tried from inside phpMyAdmin). As long as I stay below 4 or 5 tables it works. For the 2nd example I get a "check your syntax" error...

Comment: @nikc Correct me if my edit of the A was wrong :) Thanks for all your help. Works good as long as I take a decent number of tables to join.

Comment: @kaiser: entirely identical rows should not be repeated. If there is repetition, one or more tables has 2 or more rows matching the join condition.

Comment: If child tables have identical records and only distinct rows should be returned, then try to use UNION clause instead of UNION ALL.

Comment: @Devart & nikc Thanks. Guess I imported the tables twice by accident.